# Why are the object proportions from Blender to Unity not being respected?

Tags: objects, unity

There is an object in Blender which, when transferred to Unity, does not match one part.

In Blender:
[image]

In Unity:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please replace the file link to an upload on [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), which is a permanent hosting service.

Comment: @Leander Now it's ok?

Comment: Well first of all, you need to apply scale to all your models (which are all different by the way). In object mode select each part individually and press "Ctrl+A" and apply scale. See if that works first.

Comment: @MarkJackson It's works. Can you make answer?